# How to inject a Logger in an enum

Tags: java, cdi

When I try to inject my Logger producer in an enum, I get a NPE. How can I inject a Logger in an enum?

Example:

```
public enum MyEnum {

    HI("Hi there!"),
    HELLO("Hello mister!");

    @Inject
    private Logger log;

    private final String greeting;

    private MyEnum(String greeting) {
        this.greeting = greeting;
//        this.log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    }

    public String getGreeting() {
        log.debug("Method getGreeting called");
        return this.greeting;
    }

}
```

This class gives me a NPE on the `log.debug()` line. When I remove the `@Inject` and uncomment the `this.log` line it works.

Testcase looks like this:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class CoverKindTest {

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
                .addClass(MyEnum.class)
                .addClass(LoggerProducer.class)
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void testEnum() {
        MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.HI;
        String greeting = myEnum.getGreeting();
        assertThat("Should give the greeting.", greeting, is("Hi there!"));
    }

}
```

Complete testable project for this question can be found here, `MyEnum.class` is the original question, `MyEnum1.class` is the solution without injection (working, but not what I am looking for) and `MyEnum2.class` is a suggested answer.

Edit: Updated the GitHub repo with a working solution.
https://github.com/martijnburger/how-to-inject-a-logger-in-an-enum

Comment: I think the reason is you use CDI to inject the Logger and it doesn't work because your enum is not a bean => your logger stays null.

Comment: How are you calling the enum? For Inject to work the class in which its being used should be the proxy created object. I'm guessing you're directly calling `MyEnum.HI.getGreeting()`, in which case the corresponding DI framework will not know it needs to inject some variables. Can you paste the code of how you invoked this?

Comment: @BandiKishore Yes, that's the way I am using it. I added the testcase. Is there a way to use the `LoggerProducer` for logging in this situation?

Comment: If the container does not recognize enums as a type that can be an entity or a bean, you will be getting this error. Can you apply these to Enums? Does it compile?

Comment: How does the container know it needs to go through the annotations of your enum?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you question.

Comment: The @Inject may be there, but if the container does not know it needs to process it, it will not happen. So you need an annotation, *.xml entry, something that tells the container that type is to be loaded and processed.

Comment: Makes no sense to me. Why wouldn't the container know how to process the @Inject? What annotation are you talking about?

Comment: Can you @Autowire an enum field? It may work as it may not

Comment: The container will process the annotations of the types it keeps track of. If your enum is not managed by the container, how does the container know?

Comment: You are referring to Spring. This is a Java CDI question.

Comment: @Test you have MyEnum .... MyEnum type was probably loaded by the same classloader that loaded the test class. There is nothing that tells that container to load the enum separately to process the annotations. But I may be wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution that works!

I created a helper class as follows:

```
public class LoggerHelper {

    private static Logger logger;

    private void injectLogger(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object context, 
            Logger logger) {
        LoggerHelper.logger = logger;
    }

    public static Logger getLogger() {
        return logger;
    }

}
```

Now I can inject the logger in the Enum using:

```
private final Logger log = LoggerHelper.getLogger();
```

Answer (score 3):

This direct injection won't work since enum is static.
You can either create a new logger in your enum class

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Myenum.class.getName());
```

Comment: Yes. I understand that, and I know it works. The question is however, how to user CDI injection for logging in an enum.

Comment: You can create a inner class LogInjector in your enum class and inject that logger in your inner class

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: You can try something like this.
public enum MyEnum {

    public static class LogInjector {
        @Inject
     private Logger log;
    }
}

Comment: When I try to use that construct, I get the error that a non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context. I cannot make the log variable static, because than I cannot @Inject it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Enums cannot be injected, as they're static.

If you still want injection (instead of just creating the Logger), then you need to create a static class inside your enum that has either setter or constructor injection.  When the setter or constructor gets called by the DI framework, take the value it gives you and assign it yourself to a static value in the enum.

The enum can access it now as needed.  Beware though, the value will be null if your class was not injected yet.

Something like this:

```
  public enum MyEnum {

      HI("Hi there!"),
      HELLO("Hello mister!");

      private static Logger log;

      private final String greeting;

      private MyEnum(String greeting) {
          this.greeting = greeting;
      }

      public String getGreeting() {
          log.debug("Method getGreeting called");
          return this.greeting;
      }

      @Component
      public static class InjectionHelper {
        @Inject
        public InjectionHelper(Logger log) {
          MyEnum.log = log;
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I still get the NPE. Please look at my updated question. Whats wrong? What do you mean by "if the class was not injected yet"?

Comment: You didn't do what I said.

Comment: I really wouldn't do this just for a logger though... but it's your code.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. Thanks for the example, and sorry, but this still gives me the NPE.

Comment: I agree that it is not suitable for the Logger, however the actual Producer I am using is a bit more complex, I thought I translate it to a simple example and try to get that working first.

Comment: I've added a GitHub repo, Enum2 is your answer and gives me a NPE.

Comment: This works for Spring.  The only thing I missed in my example above was the @Component annotation on the helper class.  If it doesn't work for yours then you'll have to look for a hack there.

Comment: Also, you will keep getting the NPE if you in some fashion access this enum *before* the injection happened.  Add a log line in the Helper to see if it was injected already, and if necessary, add a null check in the Enum.  This way if you cannot avoid the early access it will work later.

Comment: I don't know a lot about Spring. Is there a CDI alternative for the @Component annotation?

Comment: I tried `javax.ejb.Stateless` as an alternative. This will not work on a inner class and if I make it a standalone class, it will not accept a static class.

Comment: As a standalone class it does not need to be static (they're static by default).

Comment: Without static still getting the NPE.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a Singleton Service class (created by your respective DI Framework - say Spring), Inject this log inside that class and use it in your enum.

Here is a sample code which works. (Replace the Service annotation with a bean tag for this class in XML, if you're using XML way  of doing it. Also you can neglect the lombok `@Getter` annotation and replace it with a static getter)

```
// Service which is actually a Utility class but have DI Managed Beans.
@Service("staticService")
public class StaticService {

    @Getter
    private static Logger log;

    @Inject
    StaticService(Logger log) {
        StaticService.log = log;
    }
}
```

Now in your corresponding Enum:

```
public String getGreeting() {
        StaticService.getLog().debug("Method getGreeting called");
        return this.greeting;
    }
```

I used a similar pattern for one of my classes (In Spring) and the injection worked.

**Logic:**

1. We first create an instance of the class (singleton instance) and inject the needed variable in the constructor.
2. Since this gets called during spring initialization (During Application startup), the log is initialized and we manually assign the static variable of log with the injected object in the constructor.

**Note:**

1. Don't forget the Inject annotation in the constructor Args.
2. Better to not provide a setter method to this log object. As its static and shared, we don't want people to replace this value post-construction. (Making it final is not an option as its static).

Comment: I am using CDI, not spring. but I think I understand what you are saying and I tried it. It still gives me a NPE on the getLog() method.

Comment: That's weird. If CDI knows about Logger object then this method should work. As its similar to any other Class level Injection. I'm not sure about CDI but could there be any annotation like @Service or an XML entry to create bean instance for StaticService class? Maybe you can add that and see.

Comment: Ah, yes `@Singleton` annotation. Did that help?

Comment: Nope. Sorry. Added a public GitHub project to the question if you want to take a look.

Comment: Found a solution that works. See my answer. Thanks for the help, you put me on the right track!